# How to convert genotyping data

Tags: r, genetics

I have this `dataframe` (approx dim of 446664 X 234) called `mydf` (`dput` is provided). This `dataframe` has columns `REF` and `ALT`.

`REF` has only one letter in every row, but `ALT` could have one, two or even three letters separated by  a comma (","), the rest of the columns (samples columns) are the columns where I need to do all the work.

Considering any letter in `REF` to be 0 and the first letter in `ALT` as 1, second letter 2 and third letter 3, respectively, I need to make a function so that:

1. I can replace the number in all sample columns (i.e. except in REF and ALT) with the letters and if there is "./.";
2. Fill them with NA/NA and collapse the "/" to get paired letters in every cell.
3. Finally I need to invert all the sample columns across the rows (`transpose`) as shown in the `result`. Thank you!

   ```
   mydf<-
   structure(list(REF = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
   "C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), ALT = structure(c(6L, 6L, 
   1L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "A,C", "A,G", "A,T", "C", "C,G", 
   "C,T", "G", "G,T", "T"), class = "factor"), X860 = structure(c(1L, 
   3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("./.", "0/0", "0/1", "0/2", "1/1"
   ), class = "factor"), X861 = structure(c(1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("./.", 
   "0/0", "0/1", "0/2", "1/1", "1/2"), class = "factor"), X862 = structure(c(6L, 
   3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("./.", "0/0", "0/1", "0/2", "1/1", 
   "2/2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("REF", "ALT", "X860", 
   "X861", "X862"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
   ```

Expected output:

```
X860 NANA TC GG NANA NANA
X861 NANA CG GG NANA NANA 
X862 GG TC NANA CC NANA
```

Comment: In the case of `1/2`, the `1` signifies the `REF` ie. `T` and `2` for 'G' from `C/G` in the ALT?  Or it is just `CG`?  But, then I am confused with `0/1` as `TC`?

Comment: @akrun If I understood correctly it's a 0 based index of the letters in the two columns `REF` and `ALT` as if they were concatenated. So for A C,G 0 =A, 1=C, 2=G

Comment: @Tensibai  I was thinking that if there is anywhere 0 appear, that is the `REF` letter to be replaced and for other values, it is based on the position of values in 'ALT' ie. in the case of `C,G`, it might be `1/2` or so.  Anyway, it looks complicated for a big dataset to try with `apply`

Comment: @akrun I'll give this a try and see if can get something working :)

Comment: @Tensibai  Go ahead.  Good luck!

Comment: @akrun any letter in REF is referenced 0, then first letter in ALT is reference as 1, second letter(separated by comma) is referenced as 2 and so forth for the replacement in sample columns. The final result will have collapse "/". Thanks!

Comment: @user277653 Yes, i think so, but the OP's dataset is big, so a data.table or dplyr solution might be more useful

Comment: @Tensibai, you are right!

Comment: @MAPK was your data delivered in a data frame or do you have source data in a format like VCF or BGEN? I may have some ways to handle this data much more easily if your data was delivered in one of those standard formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this but I'm quite unsure of the performance of it:

```r
letters <- strsplit(paste(mydf$REF,mydf$ALT,sep=","),",") # concatenate the letters to have an index to work on from the numbers
values <- t(mydf[,3:ncol(mydf)]) # let's work on each column needing values
nbval <- ncol(values) # Save time for later and save the length of values 

#Prepare the two temp vectors used later
chars <- vector("character",2) 
ret <- vector("character",nbval)

#Loop over the rows (and transpose the result)
t(sapply(rownames(values),
   function(x) { 
     indexes <- strsplit(values[x,],"/") # Get a list with pairs of indexes

     for(i in 1:nbval) { # Loop over the number of columns :/
       for (j in 1:2) { # Loop over the pair 
         chars[j] <- ifelse(indexes[[i]][j] == ".", "NA",letters[[i]][as.integer(indexes[[i]][j])+1]) # Get NA if . or the letter with the correct index at this postion
       }
       ret[i] <- paste0(chars[1],chars[2]) # concatenate the two chars
     }
     return(ret) # return this for this row
   }
))
```

Output with sample data:

```
     [,1]   [,2] [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  
X860 "NANA" "TC" "GG"   "NANA" "NANA"
X861 "NANA" "CG" "GG"   "NANA" "NANA"
X862 "GG"   "TC" "NANA" "CC"   "NANA"
```

---

Updated version of the function (as the rest of code does not change) from comment:

```
#Loop over the rows (and transpose the result)
t(sapply(rownames(values),
   function(x) {
     indexes <- strsplit(values[x,],"/") # Get a list with pairs of indexes
     for(i in 1:nbval) { # Loop over the number of columns :/
       if (values[x,i] == "./.") { # test if we have ./. and if yes, set to NA
         ret[i] <- "NA"
       } else { # if it's not ./. then try to find the corresponding letters
         for (j in 1:2) { # Loop over the pair 
           chars[j] <- ifelse(indexes[[i]][j] == ".", "NA",letters[[i]][as.integer(indexes[[i]][j])+1]) # Get NA if . or the letter with the correct index at this postion
         }
         ret[i] <- paste0(chars[1],chars[2]) # concatenate the two chars
       }
     }
     return(ret) # return this for this row
   }
))
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
X860 "NA" "TC" "GG" "NA" "NA"
X861 "NA" "CG" "GG" "NA" "NA"
X862 "GG" "TC" "NA" "CC" "NA"
```

Comment: Why do I get this error message: NAs introduced by coercion?

Comment: I bet you have somewhere 2 where there's not two letter in ALT

Comment: Do you mean in this line: chars <- vector("character",2) ?

Comment: Absolutely not. I mean in your source data you have something like C T 0/2 the 2 can't match a letter

Comment: Yes I do have 0/2 in several instances. How do I fix this then?

Comment: I can't fix your input data for you nor guess what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I know and I am really thankful to you for the help you have provided. However, my data has 0/0,0/1,0/2 and 0/3 variations and based on that I need to get the letters from REF and ALT.

Comment: I understood what you wish but I can't tell where you have a number with does not match with the number of letters present. I.e ref = T ALT=C,G number 0/3 there's no letter for 3

Comment: How do you insert NA only in place of NANA if you are to replace NA for "./." and not just "."?

Comment: @MAPK Sorry for the delay. For this case the code would be slightly different, testing first if the entry is `./.`. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is my try:

```
#ref alt together, we will access by index of each allele
refalt <- paste(mydf$REF,mydf$ALT,sep=",")

#loop over for each SNP column
t(
  sapply(3:5, function(snp){
    #take one SNPs
    x <- as.character(mydf[,snp])
    sapply(1:length(x), function(ix){
      #get genotype and make numeric alleles
      geno <- unlist(strsplit(x[ix],"/",fixed=TRUE))
      a1 <- as.numeric(geno[1])+1
      a2 <- as.numeric(geno[2])+1
      #match with refalt on ix
      allele <- unlist(strsplit(refalt[ix],",",fixed=TRUE))
      #output - here I would prefer to output "NANA" as NA but it is up to you.
      paste0(allele[a1],allele[a2])
    })
  })
)

#output
#       [,1]   [,2] [,3]   [,4]   [,5]  
# [1,] "NANA" "TC" "GG"   "NANA" "NANA"
# [2,] "NANA" "CG" "GG"   "NANA" "NANA"
# [3,] "GG"   "TC" "NANA" "CC"   "NANA"
```

Comment: How do I introduce respective column name in each rows? Why do I get this error message: NAs introduced by coercion?

Comment: NA introduced warning, "." dot cannot be changed - coerced - to a number, so it becomes NA.

Comment: "How do I introduce respective column name in each rows?" - I don't understand this question, maybe cbind()?

Comment: How do you put NA only in place of NANA  in output?

Comment: @user277653 This should work: `df[ df=="NANA" ] <- NA`